# Can I use RCX sensors and motors with the NXT brick?

Tags: mindstorms, nxt, compatibility, rcx

I have a bunch of motors and sensors from the original Mindstorms set. It seems a shame I can't use these with the more recent NXT set. Are there any unofficial modifications that allow you to convert the cables?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

LEGO used to sell Converter Cables for Mindstorms NXT at a price of £8.99 / US$9.99 for 3 cables at their online shop, they can still be bought online from stores like [Bricklink](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?SetID=8528-1).

[image: Converter cable NXT - 9V]

Considering the price of each cable converter it may be worth purchasing newer sensors/motors that are more advanced. The NXT system cables are separate from sensors and motors and come in different lengths.

[image: NXT cables]

Comment: I wish there was studs on the black adapter part!

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can use all RCX sensors and motors with a NXT brick. Don't forget about lamps, too.

The connections are different though, so as Ambo100 [says](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/713), you will need converter cables. However, if you don't want to pay the full price for them, you can also [make some yourself](http://www.philohome.com/nxtcables/nxtcable.htm) which isn't really that difficult.

The other thing you need to consider is how to use them with your programming environment; for the LEGO-provided NXT-G there is a special library of blocks which you can add. You can find it on the [LEGO Education downloads site](http://education.lego.com/en-us/searchresult?q=RCX+Legacy+Sensor+Blocks+for+NXT+Software). The description of this library is as follows:

> **Description**
>   The Legacy Sensor Block Library is available for users who have purchased the LEGO MINDSTORMS NXT Software Version 2.0. The library adds support to RCX actions and sensors to the NXT Software. It includes blocks for the RCX motor, lamp, touch sensor, light sensor, rotation sensor and temperature sensor. The blocks are available in English, French, German, Japanese, and Dutch.

On a related note, if you want to use Power Functions motors and lights, you can do so by using the two converter cables (NXT-9V + 9V-PF). There is currently no NXT-PF conversion cable, but you could make one as easily as you would make a NXT-9V cable. There is also a [third-party infrared link "sensor"](http://www.hitechnic.com/cgi-bin/commerce.cgi?preadd=action&key=NIL1046) which allows an NXT brick to control PF elements via the normal infrared receiver.