# Programming EV3 with NXC

Tags: ev3, nxc

I'm trying to run  NXC programs (all run well on NXT) but when trying run it on EV3 I find an error. The download from computer to EV3 runs well but trying to run the program with RUN EV3, I have an error.
Can somebody help me with this issue?

Comment: Relevant: http://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/1838/will-mindstorms-ev3-be-backwards-compatible

Comment: It's a real pity. Because NXC worked perfectly. It was complete without being overly complicated. Lejos, for me, is too elaborate. RobotC does work pretty well. But when doing "behavior" things or multitasking it switches quite slowly between tasks. I work with MindStorms at school and as a hobby. NXC works good for both.

Answer (score 1):

NXC compiles to machine code that runs in a virtual machine running on the NXT. The EV3 has a completely different virtual machine that is not compatible. So, of course programs compiled for the NXT will not run on the EV3.

The developer of NXC and BrixCC started working on support for the EV3 when it first came out, but has not been actively working on it for some time now. If you are interested, you can find more information at https://mindboards.org/ (search for "BrixCC EV3").

I you would like to use a text based language for the EV3, the most active projects are:

- http://www.ev3dev.org
- http://www.lejos.org
- http://www.monobrick.dk
- http://www.robotc.net